# How to change the height of the UITextField in an AlertView?

Tags: ios, uialertview

I have an AlertView that's set for text input, but the default textfield's height doesn't look visually appealing. Is there a way to change it without making a custom alert view?

Comment: Are you using `UIAlertView` or `UIAlertController` (you should be using the latter).

Comment: I tried with UIAlertView at first, but now I am using a UIAlertController

Comment: I've never tried this but try changing the height of the text field in the block handler for `addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler`

Comment: haha i just tried that too. It does change the textfield itself, but the box doesn't change.

Comment: @Nil2k15, what "box"?

Comment: When the AlertView is in Input Mode, theres a visual box (rectangle) that appears within the AlertView. Changing the frame or transforming the textfield doesn't have an effect on the box.